# Aggregate dimension values by month and year

Tags: looker-studio

I've been tracking a bunch of dates (with format string) under the dimension 'Product' in Google Analytics.

In Data Studio, I then have a simple Line Chart with all these dates (x) and their respective List Views. Like this:

[image]

Is there a way to aggregate these days by month and year?

Like this:

2020-08
2020-09
2020-10
and so on...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Summary

The below creates a Date field and then uses the Date field in a Time Series chart with Date Granularity.

### 1) Product_Date

Creating the [TODATE](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300) Data Source-level [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below to extract a Google Data Studio recognised Date field (where `Product` represents the current Date field):

```
TODATE(Product, "%Y-%m-%d", "%Y%m%d")
```

GIF to visualise the process:

[image]

### 2) Date Granularity

- ***Chart Type***: [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697)
- ***Date Range Dimension***: `Product_Date`
- ***Dimension***: `Product_Date`; set the Granularity as required (Year, Year Month, etc)
- ***[Drill-down](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9319405) (Optional)***: Select and set multiple Date Granularity as well as a default Drill-down.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/71a1f1be-b5e3-4530-8f89-c56c8107a261) and a GIF to elaborate to the above:

[image]